# Bind all the li except the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind all the li except the last one using jQuery.
, is it possible to do that in one line,I've tried to Google it without any success.

```
$('#elementName li').on('click', someFunction);
$('#elementName li:last-child').off('click');
```

?

Comment: `$('#elementName li:not(:last)').off('click');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.not()` selector with `:last` to filter out last element:

```
 $('#elementName li').not(':last').on('click', someFunction);
```

or

```
 $('#elementName li:not(:last)').on('click', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('#elementName li:not(:last)').on('click', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 5):

how about

```
$('#elementName li')
    .not($('#elementName li:last-child'))
    .on('click', someFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
$('#elementName li:not(:last-child)').on('click', yourFunc);
```